# How to convert a pandas column that contains numpy arrays to nd array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'a':[np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4,5,6])]
}
)
```

i want to have a numpy array like following extracted from the `a` column:

```
 array([[1., 2., 3.],
   [4., 5., 6.]])
```

i can do it like below:

```
 for i, row in df.iterrows():
     t_arr[i,:] = row["a"]
```

but i am looking for a solution without for loop. `.values` and `to_numpy()` don't return the desired results

Comment: You should show the un-desired result from `values`.  It's a useful starting point for creating an answer.  I expect it is an object dtype array with 2 array elements.  In general they might differ in shape, but if they do match, they can then be joined into one array as demonstrated in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.stack` to create a 2d numpy array.

Either from the series object of your `a` column:
`np.stack(df['a'].values)`

Or from the whole DataFrame:
`np.stack(df.values.flatten())`

Edit: You don't even need to call `.values`. You can just call `np.stack` on the series object.

Comment: `np.stack` iterates through the argument (such as a Series) and creates a 2d  array from each.  Skipping the `values` doesn't save time.  Leaving it in probably makes the action clearer to humans.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
np.vstack(df['a'])
```

which returns:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```